# Почему ставитcя тире в данном предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, тире

> На глазах у читателей разворачивается настоящая драма: в центре
> повествования – группа нигилистов во главе с Петром Верховенским...

С двоеточием понятно, но тире тут при чем? Потому что *центр* – подлежащее, а *повествование* – сказуемое?

Answer (score 2):

В предложении после двоеточия отсутствует сказуемое:
*где?* – ***в центре*** (обстоятельство), *чего?* – ***повествования*** (дополнение) ***[находится]*** *что?* –   ***группа...*** (подлежащее). Интонационная пауза способствует постановке тире.

> 1. Тире ставится при наличии паузы в так называемых эллиптических предложениях (самостоятельно употребляемых предложениях с отсутствующим сказуемым): *Влево, в углу, у дверей, на табурете — ведро воды для жаждущих* (Пом.); *За калиткой — третий плац, строевой, необыкновенной величины* (Купр.).

Источник: [**Тире в неполном предложении**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=93) (справочник Розенталя).